# Variable set inside of callback function can't be accessed outside

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

I am setting a variable inside the MySQL query result `callback` function so that I can access it later, but if I try to do `if(!data)` in the next step it says `data` is not defined.

```js
await connection.query('SELECT * FROM `licenses` WHERE `licensekey` = ?', [key], function (error, results, fields) {
      let data = results[0]
    })
```

The key variable is defined properly and I am  able to do `console.log(results[0])` inside of that function.

Comment: where is this ```if (!data)```?

Comment: Declare  it outside  and assingn it inside .  eg Let data  = '';

Comment: the if statement is after this, and yes at very top ive done let data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `callback` passed to `.query` function. `await` won't be waiting for `callback` to be executed here.

Try wrapping it inside `Promise` as below

```
const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `licenses` WHERE `licensekey` = ?', [key], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) reject(error);
    else resolve(results[0]);
  });
});

if(!data) {
  // ...
}
```